# Cobalt theme for Geany?

Tags: gedit, programming, geany

Is there any cobalt theme available for Geany Editor just like Gedit cobalt theme? Also how to install these themes. Is there any way we can create our own theme for these types of editors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about a Cobalt theme but there are many themes for Geany on GitHub (https://github.com/codebrainz/geany-themes).